# Pass in variable to Mako template

Tags: python, mako

In Perl, by using Template Toolkit, here is what I do

**Perl**

```
my $vars = {
    name     => 'Count Edward van Halen',
};

$tt->process('letters/overdrawn', $vars)
    || die $tt->error(), "\n";
```

**HTML**

```
Dear [% name %],
```

In [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/usage.html#usage_file) template, how can I do so? Check through their `render` function, doesn't get much hint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use named arguments

```
mytemplate.render(myvar1="var1", mydict=dict())
```

In the mako side you'd do

```
${myvar1}
% for val in mydict:
    ${val}
% endfor
```

Comment: `yourTemplateInstance.render(xyz = "value of xyz")` Check out http://diveintopython.org/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html